# Field not automatically included in poline

Tags: acumatica

I want to create a purchase order, the fields are not calculated :                   line.SiteID ; line.LineType ; line.ExpenseAcctID ; line.POAccrualAcctID
while in manual entry everything works correctly

```
      order.OrderType = "RO"; 
      order.Status="H";
      order.BranchID=une_commandevente.BranchID;
      order = poOrder.CurrentDocument.Insert(order);
      order.VendorID = cmdfrs.Usrfournisseur;
      order.OrderDate = DateTime.Today;
      order.OrderDesc = "XXX";    
      order.VendorRefNbr="XXX";
      poOrder.CurrentDocument.Update(order);          

      foreach (SOLine une_lignevente in PXSelectReadonly<SOLine,Where<SOLine.orderNbr, Equal<Required<SOLine.orderNbr>>,And<SOLine.orderType,Equal<Required<SOLine.orderType>>>>>.Select(this.Base,une_commandevente.OrderNbr,une_commandevente.OrderType))
      {
        var une_ligneventeext = une_lignevente.GetExtension<SOLineExt>();
        if (une_ligneventeext.Usrfournisseur==cmdfrs.Usrfournisseur)                  
        {
              var line = poOrder.Transactions.Insert();
              line.OrderType = "RO";
              line.InventoryID = une_lignevente.InventoryID;
              line.SiteID=3;  
              line.LineType = "NS";  
              line.ExpenseAcctID=39367;
              line.POAccrualAcctID=39367;       
              line.OrderQty= une_lignevente.Qty;
              line.UOM=une_lignevente.UOM;
              poOrder.CurrentDocument.Update(order);   
              poOrder.Transactions.Update(line);          
        }
      }

    poOrder.CurrentDocument.Update(order);
    poOrder.Actions.PressSave();
```

Thanks
Xav

Answer (score 0):

There are a few adjustments needed in your logic:

- For the header's cache, use the main view (*Document*) instead of *CurrentDocument*
- For the header DAC, assign the Key values, then insert the row in the cache and then assign the rest of the values
- For the iteration, there is no need to update the header's cache
- For the grid DAC, there is no need to explicitly indicate the key values as those are defaulted from the header based on [PXDBDefault] attribute
- I'd also recommend to update the cache after there is a known field that triggers events. For instance, entering the Vendor, defaults the vendor location.

Try this modified (and simplified) version:

```
  order.OrderType = "RO"; 
  order = poOrder.Document.Insert(order);

  order.OrderDate = DateTime.Today;
  order.VendorID = cmdfrs.Usrfournisseur;
  poOrder.Document.Update(order);

  order.BranchID=une_commandevente.BranchID;      
  order.OrderDesc = "XXX";    
  order.VendorRefNbr="XXX";
  poOrder.Document.Update(order);          

  foreach (SOLine une_lignevente in PXSelectReadonly<SOLine,Where<SOLine.orderNbr, Equal<Required<SOLine.orderNbr>>,And<SOLine.orderType,Equal<Required<SOLine.orderType>>>>>.Select(this.Base,une_commandevente.OrderNbr,une_commandevente.OrderType))
  {
    var une_ligneventeext = une_lignevente.GetExtension<SOLineExt>();
    if (une_ligneventeext.Usrfournisseur==cmdfrs.Usrfournisseur)                  
    {
          POLine line = new POLine();
          line = poOrder.Transactions.Insert(line);

          line.InventoryID = une_lignevente.InventoryID;
          poOrder.Transactions.Update(line);

          line.SiteID=3;  
          poOrder.Transactions.Update(line);

          line.ExpenseAcctID=39367;
          line.POAccrualAcctID=39367;       
          poOrder.Transactions.Update(line);

          line.OrderQty= une_lignevente.Qty;
          line.UOM=une_lignevente.UOM;
          poOrder.Transactions.Update(line);
    }
  }

poOrder.Actions.PressSave();
```

Also, I'd recommend testing this in a fresh environment w/o customizations. Create a test button that instantiates the graph and creates a PO with a couple of lines.

Comment: Thanks Fernando, I try your solution but I have the same problem, several fields is not automatic as linetype. Xav

Comment: is the proposed solution getting closer? are some of the fields previously failing now being defaulted correctly?

Comment: Unfortunately no, it's working for soorder, I don't understand why 

Comment: can you test this in a fresh environment without customizations? This is pretty standard.
Also, can you package it in a customization package and send it over in order to test it locally?